# Adobe Acrobat - Limit input of a number Filed in a range 0-10

Tags: adobe-acrobat, forms

I have this form In which you have to enter some scores from 1 to 10 and in the last field you have the sum of the previous fields.

So far so good, I have the fields where you can only enter numbers and the last fields that sums the previous, the thing is that I don't know how to limit the input of numbers from 1 to 10, any ideas?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the properties for a text form field:

[image]

Set the format for the field to `Number`:

[image]

Then in validate, you can choose your range:

[image]

[image]